# In python, calculate the differnce in time from a file's 1st and last line

Tags: python, file-io

I have a log file with following structure:

```
2014-04-28 16:09:51:579491  Computer    0   4
2014-04-28 16:09:55:636024  Computer    0   6
2014-04-28 16:09:57:133587  Computer    0   8
2014-04-28 16:09:58:545286  Computer    0   10
2014-04-28 16:09:59:835178  Computer    0   12
2014-04-28 16:10:01:015113  Computer    0   14
2014-04-28 16:10:03:132038  Computer    0   16
2014-04-28 16:10:04:373344  Computer    0   18
2014-04-28 16:10:05:474140  Computer    0   20
2014-04-28 16:10:06:334320  Computer    0   22
```

I am trying to find the time taken, which can be achieved by calculating the difference between the time values of first and last line. How can I extract the values in order to proceed? Also, I want the numerical values on the extreme right side of the lines and store it into a list.

For now, I have this to read first and last line.

```
newf1=open("userdata.txt","r+")
a=newf1.readlines()
fline=a[0]
lline=a[-1]
print fline,lline
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Once you've retrieved the lines (as you've already done), you can slice out the date, e.g.:

```
>>> "2014-04-28 16:09:51:579491  Computer    0   4"[:26]
'2014-04-28 16:09:51:579491'
```

Given that, you can parse it with [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). I'll leave you to figure out [the appropriate format codes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). Once you've parsed your two dates into `datetime` objects, you can just subtract them to get a `timedelta` object, which you can deal with as you please. Ta-da!

As for retrieving the last values of each line, you can call `split` with no arguments to split on whitespace and retrieve the last item with `[-1]`. Then just store those in a list, again as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
def getvalues(x):
    x=x.split(' ')
    [year,month,day]=x[0].split('-')
    [hour,minute,second,mili]=x[1].split(':')
    rightnumbers=x[-1]
    return [year,month,day,hour,minute,second,mili],rightnumbers

def getdate(d1,d2):
    labels=['years','months','days','hours','minutes','seconds','miliseconds']
    v=[str(abs(int(i[1])-int(i[0])))+' '+labels.pop(0) for i in zip(d1,d2)]
    v=[str(i) for i in v if i[0][0]!='0']
    v[-1]='and '+str(v[-1])
    return ','.join(v)

#then call with this:
newf=getvalues(fline)
newl=getvalues(lline)
print getdate(newf[0],newl[0])
listyouwanted=[newf[1],newl[1]]
```